# React Native - Is this possible to access the camera by using the CameraRoll Api?

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, camera-roll

I am working on my app project which also deals with the camera, photos & videos.
I want to use the standard APIs not third party developers APIs, by standard APIs i mean those APIs which are documented on the react native official [website](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/).

I found `CameraRoll` API in the [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll) and my question is whether it is possible to achieve the following using this API?

- Access Photos & Videos
- Select Photos & Videos
- Open camera and take Photos & Record Videos

I am sure about the first two that we can achieve, but doubtful about the third. Can anyone tell that can we achieve the third by using `CameraRoll` API?

Comment: Try first. Then put some code here, if not working.

Answer (score 0):

- Yes
- No
- No

The documentation clearly says what the API can and can't do. `getPhoto()` will only return a promise containing an array with image information, no actual images. You'd have to implement a custom viewer. 
And it can't access the camera, only stored files.

If that's what you want to do `react-native-image-picker` is your best friend.